# Disposing of LINQPad datacontext

Tags: c#, dispose, linqpad

So I'm running into a few OutOfMemory exceptions when I run some large queries using a `foreach()` loop in LINQPad. A colleague of mine (who is on vacation now), recommended that I would throw a `using()` inside my `foreach()`, so it would create a new table reference (and dispose, I guess) every time it loops. However, I forgot the right way to do it, and I can't seem to find anything helpful on Google.

Example: I have a **Customer** table, so my `foreach()` would go something like this, normally:

```
foreach(var customer in listOfCustomerIds) {
    var sum = Customer
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == customer)
        .Jobs
        .Where(x => x.Deleted == null)
        .Where(x => x.CustomerJobRelations.Any())
        .Sum(x => x.CustomerJobRelations.Count());
}
```

However, as I said, this gave me some OutOfMemory exceptions. Instead, he wanted me to do something like this:

```
foreach(var customer in listOfCustomerIds) {
    using(var customerTable = new TypedDataContext<Customer>()) {
        var sum = customerTable
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == customer)
            .Jobs
            .Where(x => x.Deleted == null)
            .Where(x => x.CustomerJobRelations.Any())
            .Sum(x => x.CustomerJobRelations.Count());
    }
}
```

The syntax is wrong, but I'm 100% sure he used a TypedDataContext. How he set it up, however, is completely forgotten. Anyone know how?

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense and probably doesn't compile. You are selecting a single `Customer` so you can't use `Sum` on it. `FirstOrDefault` also doesn't make sense if you use `Sum` because it returns `null` in case of no matching Id, so `Sum` throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm using sum on a `.Whatever` property on the customer. `Whatever` is simply a list of `Whatevers`. I guess you missed that :)

Comment: No, you're using `Sum` on what `FirstOrDefault` returned: `table.FirstOrDefault(..).Sum(..)`. `First`/`FirstOrDefault`/`Single`/`SingleOrDefault` all return only a single instance (or `null`), so you can't use `Sum` on it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ah, my bad, that's right. Anyway, my example doesn't run and the syntax is wrong (as I already said). Keep on topic, so I can get my issue resolved, please.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Updated the model. A customer has a `Jobs` list that I need to grab all the `CustomerJobRelations` from, that meet the `Where()` criterias. Unfortunately, you're wrong. If I run even just 500 queries through LINQPad, it will crash with the OutOfMemory exception. "you are just selecting a single int" - perhaps, but it's still crashing because it never disposes the datacontext.

Comment: Also, I'm not trying to find out why I get a OutOfMemory exception. It's clearly because I'm running a lot of queries through LINQPad without releasing the memory. Something I can fix, if I can just remember how to construct that TypedDataContext..

Comment: Are you sure he didn't mean to create a new DataContext (eg `using (var dc = new TypedDataContext(this.Connection.ConnectionString))` ?

Comment: @sgmoore Seems like that worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen If I'm experiencing an issue with LINQPad, that can be solved by creating a new data context inside my foreach loop, what exactly do you think I'm asking? I don't care how I end up with a new data context inside my foreach loop, as long as I know how to create one. I solved this already simply by putting that code sgmoore wrote inside my foreach, then simply `dc.Customers.FirstOrDefa....`. Now it runs perfectly and I'm not running into any OutOfMemory exceptions.